# How to combine a column which shows hyper link with the columns fetched from database table

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Manage Users screen which has a `Grid` data in which I fetch the details from the users table and showing it. But I want to add another column which will be a hyperlink called `Edit`. How to do this?

This is a datagrid's content:

```
 private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable usersDT = UsersDAL.UsersDAL.select();

            allUsersGrid.ItemsSource = usersDT.DefaultView;


            allUsersGrid.Columns[0].Header = "Id";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[1].Header = "User Name";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[2].Header = "First Name";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[3].Header = "Last Name";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[4].Header = " Password";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[5].Header = "Gender";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[6].Header = "Mobile";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[7].Header = "Email";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[8].Header = "User Type";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[9].Header = "Added On";
            allUsersGrid.Columns[10].Header = "Added By";


            allUsersGrid.MinRowHeight = 50;
        }
```

I want to add another column to this `Grid` which will be an image or a text but a hyperlink. On clicking the link, I should be able to collect the data of the clicked row

Comment: You need to provide more information and some code in order to get help.

Comment: I edited the question and added my code

Comment: You can't add hyperlinks to DataTables. They're in-memory only. You have to bind it to a DataGridView Similar to what Jophy job did below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use viewmodel approach , you can add just a button in grid row and use it to open window for editing.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Edit Row">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Edit" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And in event

```
    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        object item = MyDataGrid.SelectedItem;

          //// open a window to insert data, or make current row editable.
       }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
}
```

[edit-and-delete-operation-in-data-grid](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f100d/edit-and-delete-operation-in-data-grid-using-context-menu-p/)

[How-to-edit-selected-row-in-Datagrid-in-WPF](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/874611/How-to-edit-selected-row-in-Datagrid-in-WPF)